# Jetty retrying requests when Exception thrown by RequestHandler

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I notice `Jetty` is retrying calls to the specified `Handler` whenever `handle` throws an Exception.

This is unwelcome behavior but I can't seem to find the configuration setting to stop it.

I've been using Jetty for a while, but recently upgraded my environment to use `9.4.9.v20180320`. This may or may not be new behavior but I've never noticed it.

Below is a simple use case illustrating my issue. Notice how the there are two lines in the output indicating the body content, however confusingly on the second attempt the body is empty.

```
public class JettyTest extends AbstractHandler
{
    @Override
    public void handle(String arg0, Request arg1, HttpServletRequest arg2, HttpServletResponse arg3)
    throws IOException
    {
        //read request body into string
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //apache commons copy
        IOUtils.copy(arg1.getInputStream(), bos);
        String body = new String(bos.toByteArray());
        System.out.println("request body: " + body);
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.setHandler(new JettyTest());
        LocalConnector localConnector = new LocalConnector(server);
        server.addConnector(localConnector);
        server.start();
        String simpleRequest = "GET / http/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\n\r\nhi";
        String response = localConnector.getResponse(simpleRequest);
        server.join();
    }

}
```

Output

```
2018-03-26 19:47:49.590:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @327ms

request body: hi

2018-03-26 19:47:49.660:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp1349277854-12: /
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.JettyTest.handle(JettyTest.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayEndPoint$1.run(ByteArrayEndPoint.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

request body:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple things going on.

1. You have nothing handling the request (nothing in your codebase is using `Request.setHandled(true)`)
2. You have no ERROR dispatch handling.
3. You have no ErrorHandler setup.

So what happens is ...

1. Your JettyTest.handle() is called, the exception flows out.
2. The request is now in ERROR Dispatch mode.
3. The ERROR dispatch request is now sent into the handlers again for ERROR handling.

If you just make the change to this ...

```java
package jetty.errors;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.LocalConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.IO;

public class HandlerWithError extends AbstractHandler
{
    @Override
    public void handle(String s, Request request, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException
    {
        if (DispatcherType.REQUEST.equals(httpServletRequest.getDispatcherType()))
        {
            // read request body into string
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // apache commons copy
            IO.copy(httpServletRequest.getInputStream(), bos);
            String body = new String(bos.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("request body: " + body);
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Now in DispatchType: " + httpServletRequest.getDispatcherType());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
            throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.setHandler(new HandlerWithError());
        LocalConnector localConnector = new LocalConnector(server);
        server.addConnector(localConnector);
        server.start();
        String simpleRequest = "GET / http/1.1\r\n" +
                "Host: localhost:0\r\n" +
                "Connection: close\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
                "Content-Length: 2\r\n\r\nhi";
        String response = localConnector.getResponse(simpleRequest);
        server.join();
    }
}
```

You'll get the results ...

```
2018-03-27 06:47:40.074:INFO::main: Logging initialized @429ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2018-03-27 06:47:40.148:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.9.v20180320; built: 2018-03-20T07:21:10-05:00; git: 1f8159b1e4a42d3f79997021ea1609f2fbac6de5; jvm 9.0.4+11
2018-03-27 06:47:40.182:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started LocalConnector@2f490758{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}
2018-03-27 06:47:40.183:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @548ms
2018-03-27 06:47:40.287:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp2104545713-16: /
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jetty.errors.HandlerWithError.handle(HandlerWithError.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayEndPoint$1.run(ByteArrayEndPoint.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
request body: hi
Now in DispatchType: ERROR
```

Knowing all this, you can change your implementation to take advantage of this ERROR dispatch in the following way.

```java
package jetty.errors;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpTester;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.LocalConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.IO;

public class HandlerWithError
{
    public static class MyRequestHandler extends AbstractHandler
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println("MyRequestHandler.handle() - DispatcherType: " + request.getDispatcherType());
            // only work with REQUEST Dispatches
            if (!DispatcherType.REQUEST.equals(request.getDispatcherType()))
            {
                // skip this handler
                return;
            }

            // Set handled (by this handler), don't let other handlers operate on this request
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
            // read request body into string
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // apache commons copy
            IO.copy(request.getInputStream(), bos);
            String body = new String(bos.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("request body: " + body);
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }

    public static class MyErrorHandler extends AbstractHandler
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println("MyErrorHandler.handle() - DispatcherType: " + request.getDispatcherType());
            if(!DispatcherType.ERROR.equals(request.getDispatcherType()))
            {
                // skip this handler
                return;
            }

            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getWriter().println("Go away, you silly NPE fool");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
            throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        // Add your ERROR Dispatch handler first to handle dispatches for errors
        handlers.addHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
        // Add your handlers here (can be more then one)
        handlers.addHandler(new MyRequestHandler());
        // Always add DefaultHandler last, to ensure that something in your handler
        // list is calling baseRequest.setHandled(true)
        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
        server.setHandler(handlers);
        LocalConnector localConnector = new LocalConnector(server);
        server.addConnector(localConnector);
        server.start();

        try
        {
            String simpleRequest = "GET / http/1.1\r\n" +
                    "Host: localhost:0\r\n" +
                    "Connection: close\r\n" +
                    "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
                    "Content-Length: 2\r\n\r\nhi";
            HttpTester.Response response = HttpTester.parseResponse(
                    localConnector.getResponse(simpleRequest));
            System.out.println("Response: " + response);
            System.out.println(response.getContent());
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            server.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

With the output looking like this ...

```
2018-03-27 07:03:25.220:INFO::main: Logging initialized @320ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2018-03-27 07:03:25.288:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.9.v20180320; built: 2018-03-20T07:21:10-05:00; git: 1f8159b1e4a42d3f79997021ea1609f2fbac6de5; jvm 9.0.4+11
2018-03-27 07:03:25.309:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started LocalConnector@4ba2ca36{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}
2018-03-27 07:03:25.310:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @417ms
MyErrorHandler.handle() - DispatcherType: REQUEST
MyRequestHandler.handle() - DispatcherType: REQUEST
request body: hi
2018-03-27 07:03:25.399:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp525571-15: /
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jetty.errors.HandlerWithError$MyRequestHandler.handle(HandlerWithError.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayEndPoint$1.run(ByteArrayEndPoint.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
MyErrorHandler.handle() - DispatcherType: ERROR
Response: HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 29
Server: Jetty(9.4.9.v20180320)

Go away, you silly NPE fool

2018-03-27 07:03:25.423:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Stopped LocalConnector@4ba2ca36{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}
```